# jQuery jsonp not firing the success handler even with the valid json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function(data) { //not firing at all
       console.log('success');
       console.log(data);
     }
     error: function() {  //always firing even with status 200 & valid JSON response.
    console.log('error');
     }             
});
```

Comment: what is the format of the returned data? it should be `callbackMethodName({your json data})`, not `{your json data}`

Comment: You are showing your partial code, show us your full code for more clarification.

Comment: Is it cross domain request?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function(data) { //not firing at all
       console.log('success');
       console.log(data);
     },                         //You have missed a comma here..
     error: function() {  //always firing even with status 200 & valid JSON response.
    console.log('error');
     }             
});
```

- You have missed a comma.
- Just check the comment